# Postgres query performance in write-heavy database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a Postgres 9.6 database hosted on Heroku (standard-4 with 15GB cache).

One of my tables has almost 100M rows and that table gets maybe 3k inserts/updates per minute on average, but that can spike to 10x.

I have a few queries that run against that table that are basically counting rows with different columns having various values.

I also have a copy of the database that is currently getting no updates (basically idle).

Queries against the live database are much slower than queries on the copy and I don't know if this is due to the load/contention from the updates or poor query optimization on my part.

The values that the queries are counting are very common values.

```
select count(*)
from my_table
where a = '123'
  and b = 'abc'
```

There are a lot of rows with the combination of `123` and `abc`. I have created a partial index for that:

```
create index my_table_abc_123_index
on my_table (a, b)
where a = '123' and b = 'abc'
```

This seems to get me an index only scan that's fast on the copy (~0.5s) but much slower on the live DB (~26s). The costs also vary quite a lot (copy first, live second):

```
Aggregate  (cost=29751.39..29751.39 rows=1 width=8)

Aggregate  (cost=179603.59..179603.59 rows=1 width=8)
```

Those both return a count of about 1.4M and the tables are about the same size.

It also seems that when the writes go up (10x) the degradation is significant.

It's also interesting that Postgres doesn't always choose my partial indexes, opting for a full composite index on `(a, b)`, depending on the values passed for those columns.

I've read the Postgres indexing documentation and realize that for common values it's not always best to use the index (though Postgres is choosing an index in all these cases).

I'm wondering if this is the sort of difference I should be expecting between a live and idle database, and if I'm approaching creating indexes correctly for my workload (which is definitely write-heavy) or in general.

Some other details:

1. individual (full) column indexes seem much more expensive, but I've not tried individual column partial indexes.
2. the autovacuum threshold has been set pretty low (0.01) to deal with the dead rows due to lots of updates

Comment: So what do utilities like iotop, iostat, dstat, vmstat etc. tell you about the system? Assuming you're on some flavor of unix.

Comment: I don't think I have shell access to the DB host, since it's hosted with Heroku. I have some Heroku CLI utilities, but it's mostly at the DB/app level.

Comment: Look for monitoring apps etc. There are few that showed up on google. You need to know what's going on in terms of what's limiting your performance, IO, CPU, etc.

Comment: Will do, thanks @ScottMarlowe. I did add cache hit rates to my Librato dashboard, and they are lower than what Heroku recommends. Maybe that's a clue. But need more info!